YOLONAS - pose class name not found
I am working on YoloNAS-pose. I wanted to see the detected object class name. I am able to get the class name while using the model Yolo-nal only using coco database. For the same image when I tried with Yolo-nas-pose the class_names is missing. Any help on this
I tried using Yolo-nas and Yolo-nas-pose. I am expecting class_names to be visible for yolonas pose model.

Would you care to provide a bit more detailed description of what exactly you are doing - steps taken, code if applicable, etc.

I am working on an image to detect humans using Yolo-NAS, previously I did the same using YoloV8. To identify the pose, I require the keypoints. Both provides the keypoints but YoloNAS-pose result.prediction does not have the label to tell what class it belongs to,

You basically restated the description of the question. To clarify, it is not that I didn't understand the question, rather I was saying that it would be helpful if you provided more details on what exactly you are doing - source code for testing, documentation you are following, etc.. The title kind of looks like an error message but I am guessing it is not. Tbh skimming the documentation it seams like those models are trained on a single class. This makes sense because a cat does not have the same keypoints as a human. My best guess is that you don't have a class name since it's single class

sorry, and thanks for the answer. It is trained for detection of human keypoints only
